# API developer key error with Google Drive Picker

Tags: google-drive-api, picker, google-picker

I am following the picker "hello world" [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). I have already obtained the access token (AUTH_TOKEN) for the user. When the picker renders it does not show any file, Following is my debugging:

Error in the browser console:

[image]

---

Ok so I visit the URL `https://docs.google.com/picker` with all parameters supplied:

```
https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000&navHidden=true&multiselectEnabled=true&oauth_token={MY_TOKEN}&developerKey={MY_API_KEY}&hostId=127.0.0.1&relayUrl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Ffavicon.ico&nav=%28{root%3A%28%22all%22%29%2Citems%3A%28%28%22documents%22%29%2C%28%22presentations%22%29%29}%29&rpctoken={RPC_TOKEN}&rpcService={RPC_SERVICE}&thirdParty=true
```

I Received more descriptive error:

[image]

---

But I have working API key which can be used as developer key as mentioned in various places:

[image]

---

So why the "Developer Key Invalid" error? I read [Generating Keys](https://developers.google.com/console/help/?csw=1#generatingdevkeys), as mentioned there that the way to use these keys in the URL is to pass as `key={ your_key }`, But you can see above that the URL picker tries has `developerKey` param instead of `key`. So I just changed the parameter manually and picker renders perfectly and I was successfully able to see my drive files in picker.

Can anyone tell me why the picker is trying to use `developerKey` parameter instead of `key`? And what is the workaround? Am i doing something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have removed this line `setDeveloperKey(developerKey)` from the `createPicker` function and it works well. I don't know if it is important to set developer key in picker, but it works without it also.

Comment: This really solved the problem but how? Moreover, shouldn't Developer key be a mandatory field?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh I have no idea but it is still working till now :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use a server key, and not your client ID or client secret.
This key is used to link your app project with the API calls.

It works fine for me using setDeveloperKey is my picker.

my developer key is from "Public API Access -> key for browser application -> API key".

I agree that there is soo much key or ID on google making many confusion.
Hope it could help !